# Assign to variables values from rowtype parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've searched on stackoverflow and other sources, but haven't found anything useful.

I have to implement a procedure that receives a row (hence "%rowtype") from Reservation table as a parameter.

The table's name is Reservation (as attributes: id_Reservation, id_Room, price, etc).

I created an anonymous block to create the var_reservation variable, which will serve as the parameter to the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE priceCheckout(var_reservation reservation%ROWTYPE) IS
    l_idReservation NUMBER;
    l_idRoom NUMBER;
    prie INT;
    date1 DATE;
    date2 DATE;
    ex exception;

BEGIN
    l_idReservation := var_reservation.id_reservation;
    (...)
END;
```

But this is wrong. How can I correct this?

Comment: What does "this is wrong" mean? Please attach error message, full `create table reservation` command and your anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it *correctly*, it works. Have a look at the following example based on Scott's `DEPT` table:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (var_row dept%rowtype)
  2  is
  3    l_dname dept.dname%type;
  4  begin
  5    l_dname := var_row.dname;
  6
  7    dbms_output.put_line('Department name = ' || l_dname);
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_row dept%rowtype;
  3  begin
  4    select *
  5      into l_row
  6      from dept
  7      where deptno = 10;
  8
  9    p_test(l_row);
 10  end;
 11  /
Department name = ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Saying that "this is wrong" is difficult to debug. It is not an Oracle error message so ... unless you specify what is "this" and, possibly, edit the question and post copy/paste of your own SQL*Plus session (like I did) so that we'd see what you did and how Oracle responded, YOYO.